# OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1 with wrong version (1), where current version is 2 in Spring Batch code

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am developing the `Spring Batch Example – XML File To MongoDB Database`. I developed all required code, but when trying to run the main code its failing not sure why ? Any help is much appreciated. I am using `mongodb version 3.0.6`.

The code reference: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-xml-file-to-database/

The error for reference:

```
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1 with wrong version (1), where current version is 2
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao.updateStepExecution(MapStepExecutionDao.java:102) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:189) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.update(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:253) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49) [spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127) [spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:27) [classes/:na]
```

context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- stored job-meta in memory --> 
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- connect to mongodb -->
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

job-report.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" writer="mongodbItemWriter"
                    commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="mongodbItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter">
        <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
        <property name="collection" value="report" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="record" />
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/report.xml" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="reportUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">

        <property name="aliases">
            <util:map id="aliases">
                <entry key="record" value="com.mkyong.model.Report" />

                <!-- 
                <entry key="date" value="java.lang.String" />
                <entry key="impression" value="java.lang.Long" />
                <entry key="clicks" value="java.lang.Integer" />
                <entry key="earning" value="java.math.BigDecimal" />
                 -->
            </util:map>
        </property>

        <property name="converters">
            <array>
                <ref bean="reportConverter" />
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="reportConverter" class="com.mkyong.converter.ReportConverter" />
</beans>
```

report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<report>
    <record id="1">
        <date>6/1/2013</date>
        <impression>139,237</impression>
        <clicks>40</clicks>
        <earning>220.90</earning>
    </record>
    <record id="2">
        <date>6/2/2013</date>
        <impression>339,100</impression>
        <clicks>60</clicks>
        <earning>320.88</earning>
    </record>
    <record id="3">
        <date>6/3/2013</date>
        <impression>431,436</impression>
        <clicks>76</clicks>
        <earning>270.80</earning>
    </record>
    <record id="4">
        <date>3/12/2016</date>
        <impression>534,987</impression>
        <clicks>43</clicks>
        <earning>454.80</earning>
    </record>
</report>
```

Report.java

```
public class Report implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private long impression;
    private int clicks;
    private BigDecimal earning;
    // setters and getters
}
```

App.java

```
package com.mkyong;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] springConfig  = 
            {   "spring/batch/config/database.xml", 
                "spring/batch/config/context.xml",
                "spring/batch/jobs/job-report.xml" 
            };

        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("reportJob");

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

ReportConverter.java

```
public class ReportConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        //we only need "Report" object
        return type.equals(Report.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {

        Report obj = new Report();

        //get attribute
        obj.setId(Integer.valueOf(reader.getAttribute("id")));
        reader.moveDown(); //get date

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(reader.getValue());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obj.setDate(date);
        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get impression

        String impression = reader.getValue();
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        Number number = 0;
        try {
            number = format.parse(impression);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obj.setImpression(number.longValue());

        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get click
        obj.setClicks(Integer.valueOf(reader.getValue()));
        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get earning
        obj.setEarning(new BigDecimal(reader.getValue()));
        reader.moveUp();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/26302792/62201?

Comment: did you try it with a standard spring transaction manager and an in-memory database like HSQLDB (or H2 or Derby...) ?

Comment: Nope. In fact I had taken a reference from http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-xml-file-to-database/? I wonder how he was able to run his code. Could you please share code what else I need to change in my code to achieve in-memory database & spring transaction manager way?

Answer (score 0):

it should work, but you can try it with an in-memory database to see if there are any transaction problems

example config

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <description>Job database setup.</description>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ignore-failures="DROPS" is not needed, because the drop statements use "if exists" -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

you need at least [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org), apache commons-dbcp and some spring stuff like spring-jdbc

example maven config for these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${your.spring.version.here}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thnx Michael. The issue coming for the mongodb. Could you please take a look at actual code from link and guide for solution once again?

Comment: sorry i have no knowledge in mongodb, i propose you ask a another question specifically to the problem with spring batch and mongodb